# Viewpager automatic scroll without handler postdelayed and setcurrentitem

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, automatic-differentiation

I want to implement automatic viewpager scroll without using setCurrentItem() function. Because when i use setcurrentitem() with handler.postdelayed() it holds on after setting next item. and i want a smooth scroll like in recyclerview. Will it be possible to achieve it with viewpager?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with ViewPager. best carousel like is using the recylerview. but you need to custom the LayoutManager first to slow down the speed like carousel

Create Recyclerview

```
CustomLayoutManager layoutManager = new CustomLayoutManager(getActivity());
layoutManager.setSpeed(1500f);
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
```

Then Create CustomLayoutManager to change the speed of recylcerview scroll

```
public class CustomLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
    private float MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH = 1100f;
    private Context mContext;

    public CustomLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, final int position) {

        LinearSmoothScroller smoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(mContext) {
                    @Override
                    public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
                        return CustomLayoutManager.this.computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
                        return MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH/displayMetrics.densityDpi;
                    }
                };

        smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
        startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
    }

    public void setSpeed(float speed){
        this.MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH = speed;
    }
}
```

then in your activity or fragment, create Runnable

```
Runnable runNews = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                top_new_rview.smoothScrollToPosition(++counter);
                handler.postDelayed(this, replay);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                handler.removeCallbacks(runNews);
                onError(getActivity(), e);
            }
        }
    };
```